# Android-Convert byte[] to String which has 1,440,000 rows

Tags: android, byte

below is logcat result which shows out of memory problem.

it may be involved with too big byte[] array.

---

04-17 22:21:38.773: W/dalvikvm(4963): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a4d1f8)
04-17 22:21:38.781: E/AndroidRuntime(4963): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 22:21:38.781: E/AndroidRuntime(4963): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-17 22:21:38.781: E/AndroidRuntime(4963):  at java.nio.CharBuffer.put(CharBuffer.java:509)
04-17 22:21:38.781: E/AndroidRuntime(4963):  at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.allocateMore(CharsetDecoder.java:238)
04-17 22:21:38.781: E/AndroidRuntime(4963):  at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:195)
04-17 22:21:38.781: E/AndroidRuntime(4963):  at java.nio.charset.Charset.decode(Charset.java:487)
04-17 22:21:38.781: E/AndroidRuntime(4963):  at java.lang.String.(String.java:174)
04-17 22:21:38.781: E/AndroidRuntime(4963):  at java.lang.String.(String.java:141)

### 04-17 22:21:38.781: E/AndroidRuntime(4963):  at exam.militarymgrs.Draw_LOS.readFile(Draw_LOS.java:182)

Draw_LOS.java:182 is as follows.
(String s = new String(dat);)

-------Source code--------------

```
public static ArrayList<String> readFile(String fileName) {
//map data access
String sdPath;
sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/";

File file = new File(sdPath+fileName);
//String[] k = new String[1440000];
//String line = "";

ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();//consider using ArrayList<int>
try {
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] dat = new byte[fis.available()];
String s = new String(dat);
String[] k = s.split("[\\r\\n]+");
while(fis.read(dat) != -1) {;}
fis.close();

}
catch(FileNotFoundException fN) {
fN.printStackTrace();
}
catch(IOException e) {
System.out.println(e);
}
return data; 
}
```

---

A file which should be loaded is as follows

12
32
43
...

How can I read the data file without Out of Memory with fileStream??

Comment: The solution is to start with at least 8,640,000 bytes of available heap.  Or use the 3-argument version of String() (assuming UTF8 input) that would only require 4,320,000 bytes.

Comment: Jeez, you may wish to delete that code fragment, as it does not do *anything* usefull. Please visit the [IO tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html) instead, and check out how to handle streams and readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this:

```
public static String toBinaryString(byte n) {
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("00000000");
for (int bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++) {
if (((n >> bit) & 1) > 0) {
sb.setCharAt(7 - bit, '1');
}
}
return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of juggling the bytes, you'd better try a different approach, leave string parsing to the [string parser](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Scanner.html) and just collect the output:

```
public static ArrayList<int> readFile(String fileName) {  // or ArrayList<short>
    String sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/";

    Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(new File(sdPath + fileName)));

    ArrayList<int> data = new ArrayList<int>();

    while( s.hasNext() ) {
        data.add( s.nextInt() );
    }

    return data; 
}
```

Comment: this code causes GC_CONCURRENT problem and does not work properly, thank you anyway

Comment: GC_CONCURRENT is not a problem, it's the garbage collector taking care of your garbage. You may try to (temporary) replace `data.add( s.nextInt() );` with `s.nextInt();` to see if your "problem" is related to `Scanner` or `ArrayList`. If, after replacement, the "problem" goes away, you just need to choose another suitable container for your data. And, at least, you don't get `Out of Memory` exceptions, don't you?